# Converting default serializer response to desired format in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to convert the response like this using `serializers.py`, where `id` is from model `Mymodel` and `Total_login_hours` is from model

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=BIKER_STATUS_CHOICES,      default='active')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Biker Name'), max_length=254)

classLoginModel(models.Model):
    biker = models.ForeignKey(Mymodel, db_index=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    total_loginhrs = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a response as shown below by using django serializer in django rest framework:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 128,
            "totaldata": [
                {
                    "City": "abc",
                    "Locality ": "def",
                    "Biker_name": "xyz",
                    "Total_login_hours": "00:28:41",
                    "Date": "2018-01-13",
                    "Sublocality": "qwe"
                },
                {
                    "City": "asd",
                    "Locality ": "fgh",
                    "Biker_name": "zxc",
                    "Total_login_hours": "00:02:33",
                    "Date": "2018-01-14",
                    "Sublocality": "cvb"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

How can I repeat `id` in order to get the response shown below?

```
{
        "count": 2,
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "results": [
            {
                "id": 128,
                "totaldata": [
                    {
                        "City": "abc",
                        "Locality ": "def",
                        "Biker_name": "xyz",
                        "Total_login_hours": "00:28:41",
                        "Date": "2018-01-13",
                        "Sublocality": "qwe"
                    }],
                "id": 128,
                "totaldata": [
                    {
                        "City": "asd",
                        "Locality ": "fgh",
                        "Biker_name": "zxc",
                        "Total_login_hours": "00:02:33",
                        "Date": "2018-01-14",
                        "Sublocality": "cvb"
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
```